# Angular 4 - Service providers does not re-instantiate with Components

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I had my Angular 2 code logic written as new Service provider is generated when the Component is re-instantiated each time. But, I guess there are some changes in Angular 4 that prevents destruction of Service provider and therefore, I'm getting the same set values repeated instead of default set.
Is there any way to prevent this behaviour of Angular 4 ?

**Edit:**

I'm sorry. I guess I wasn't clear with my question.
I agree by default, a service dependency provided in one component is visible to all of its child components and Angular injects the same service instance into all child components that ask for that service. But my question is what if ParentComponent is destroyed.

*Example:*
ParentA  /pages/parentA
 -ChildA /pages/parentA/childA
 -ChildB /pages/parentA/childB
ParentB  /pages/parentB

ParentA has service for sharing data among its children. Default value  `let x = 0`. When we move from ParentA -> ParentB the service should destroy as per Angular 2.

Again moving from ParentB -> ParentA service should be instantiated with default values since the scope of service is with ParentA only. This was the normal behaviour as per Angular 2.4.9. Which is not reflected in Angular 4.0.1 as of now. I hope this clears the question asked.

Comment: @Sakuto I'm sorry for ambiguous question. Kindly consider the edited version.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behavior of the [Dependancy Injection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html) in `Angular`.

You can, even if it's not really recommended, have multiple instance of a service, check the [officiel documentation related to this point](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#multiple-service-instances) and their [live example](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/cb-dependency-injection/ts/eplnkr.html) to understand how.